# coherence/memcache/AppFabric for pub/sub

Tags: .net, architecture, memcached, appfabric, oracle-coherence

Looking for advice/pro's/con's on using the memory cache servers for pub/sub esp wrt a high-throughput system ( 1000's of updates/sec )

Coherence seems to have pub/sub as a use-case, not sure about the others

Would love to get some real-world input !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's pub/sub you're after you can also use a messaging solution such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Very high throughput and scales well.

Subscribe to a queue and react to messages published to them. Client libraries for a variety of languages are usually available making these systems useful for cross-platform distribution as well.

Comment: Are there any hard #'s for throughput/scalability for Rabbit ?

Comment: Latencies are measured in the sub-millisecond to one-milliscond range for a 10k message package. Message per second throughput varies with implementation and hardware but we're talking an order of magnitude above 1,000 for the common case.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to offer Hazelcast [Distributed Topic](http://www.hazelcast.com./documentation.jsp#Topic). Very light weight distributed pub/sub messaging system. 1000 updates/sec isn't much at all.

Comment: looks interesting, however it needs .net client to be considered